# Does using the words "might" and "could" consecutively in same sentence have a name or is it just improper English? (spoken English)

Tags: american-english, dialects, speech

It is now more than a coincidence, but I have heard numerous people from different parts of the country use the words "might" and "could" together in a sentence as in:

> "This might could help."

The first time I heard this, I chalked it up to a mid-sentence correction where the speaker started to say "This might help", but then changed mid-sentence to "This could help."

I've heard it now in spoken English from various people from different parts of the country. I'm curious if this is a dialect thing or if it has a name. I've also heard it repeated by the same person multiple times, both people I know and other people I don't know, so it appears not to be just a one-off mid-sentence correction, but a way of speaking that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Look up modals.  Wikipedia has some coverage of double modals. Most speakers who use them are likely to be Southerners, so encountering people from different parts of the country is odd.

Comment: ***might-could***

(double modal / stacked modal, used in some dialects, chiefly Southern US) would perhaps be able to (used to soften "could" or make it even more conditional)
***Usage notes*** 
The conjugation (with the full verb "go", for example) is:
*I might could go.
You might could go, John.
She might could go.
We might could go.
Y'all might could go. / Both of you might could go.
They might could go.* https://www.yourdictionary.com/might-could

Comment: Awesome answers! Thanks. @Xanne I've heard it from different parts of the country, but mostly in the south. It might could be that the person that said it from the north was originally from the south. ;) (See what I did there).